# What is the purpose for sending C struct over socket?

Tags: c, sockets, struct, client, cloud

I am currently doing a socket programming that involves sending c structs over the socket.

But coming to think of it,
what would be the purpose of sending the struct for?

this is a going to be implemented for networking module for client and a cloud database.

Comment: Huh?  Presumably the struct contains data that one peer has and the other one wants.  Why else do you ever send anything?

Comment: @NateEldredge i mean, what would it be possibly used for?

Comment: @YongHeeLee That depends on the struct...

Comment: Say you have a client the wants to display a list of contacts that are in a database server. The client requests from the server a list of structs that are the contacts, and then displays them on the screen in some form.

Answer (score 0):

Because the remote socket can easily parse the bytes as structure and use it, that's why, instead of reading byte per byte and converting them